# How can i get the scores and schedules using ESPN API?

Tags: api, espn

How can I get score & schedule information for all sports matches around the world? I've seen the ESPN API but its available only for strategic partners.

Are there any other solutions, or APIs or RSS feeds for this kind of information?

Answer (score 6):

If you want something that's free, it's going to be tough.  There are a lot of companies, like [Sports Data LLC](http://www.sportsdatallc.com/) whose core business model is to provide this data.

That said, I've had some success pulling JSON score data from the NFL website, inspired by Matt Croydon's blog post here:

http://postneo.com/2007/09/09/accidental-apis-nfl-edition

Answer (score 3):

**for anyone else:**

an example api endpoint for scores from ESPN is

> http://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/soccer/eng.1/scoreboard?lang=en&region=gb&calendartype=whitelist&limit=100&dates=20180407&league=eng.1

the data from this endpoint covers fixtures in the premier league on this day (i.e 2018-04-07)

the endpoint was found by following these steps

1. open Firefox browser
2. go to 'Scores' section of espn site (i.e
       http://www.espn.co.uk/football/scoreboard/_/league/all/)
3. press *ctrl +  shift + e* to open developer tools window
4. go to 'Network Monitor' tab
5. filter by 'XHR'
6. click on 'English Premier League' from dropdown-box
7. endpoint address will appear in table

'Open in new tab' to view data

---

Since the link is down in Sudhir Vadodariya''s answer, here is another one -

> www.gregreda.com/2015/02/15/web-scraping-finding-the-api/

which covers a similar problem using Chrome

Answer (score 1):

ESPN has various unpublished API endpoints that will let you get both scoreboard and schedule information.

Here is another example of a soccer endpoint, showing FIFA games:

#### Soccer:

- **FIFA**: https://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/soccer/fifa.world/scoreboard

Check the "events" key to find individual games.

You didn't specify a sport, but here are some scoreboards available for other sports/leagues:

#### Football

- **College Football**: http://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/football/college-football/scoreboard
- **NFL**: https://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/football/nfl/scoreboard

#### Baseball

- **MLB**: https://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/baseball/mlb/scoreboard
- **College Baseball**: https://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/baseball/college-baseball/scoreboard

#### Hockey

- **NHL**: http://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/hockey/nhl/scoreboard

#### Basketball

- **NBA**: https://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/basketball/nba/scoreboard
- **WNBA**: https://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/basketball/wnba/scoreboard
- **Women's College Basketball**: https://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/basketball/womens-college-basketball/scoreboard
- **Men's College Basketball**: https://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/basketball/mens-college-basketball/scoreboard

Note that the data shape may vary slightly between each endpoint, and you should be mindful of potential rate limits.

**Source**: [ESPN's hidden API endpoints](https://gist.github.com/akeaswaran/b48b02f1c94f873c6655e7129910fc3b)